# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre "curro", "trabajo" y "empleo"?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales

> Yo acabo de llegar a casa del empleo.
>
> Yo acabo de llegar a casa del curro.
>
> Yo acabo de llegar a casa del trabajo.

¿Se usa `curro`  también en Latinoamérica o es ya es obsoleto?

Comment: *curro* no se usa en Latinoamérica, al menos para referirse al trabajo (en la Argentina significa *engaño/burla* o a veces *changa* o *rebusque*), y no es cuestión de ser obsoleto porque *currar* (= *trabajar*) no apareció en España hasta finales del siglo XIX, y por lo tanto si el *curro* de la Argentina viene del *curro* de España, es algo que adoptó la Argentina y no algo que los demás perdieron. En España se popularizó especialmente en los 80 (y ahora tiene incluso más uso como otra jerga cheli) pero se debe evitar en contextos formales porque es del registro coloquial.

Comment: Solo "curro" (en España) y "trabajo" pueden usarse metafóricamente para referirse al lugar de trabajo: uno puede "ir al trabajo" pero no puede "ir al empleo". Se puede preguntar "¿Dónde queda tu trabajo?", pero no "¿Dónde queda tu empleo?". También se puede despedir a alguien "del trabajo" pero no "del empleo".

Comment: Y puedes trabajar sin estar empleado o tener empleo

Comment: En términos económicos el empleo es remunerado y formalizado (p.ej por contrato). En mi caso, soy trabajador pero no empleado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El uso de "curro", en la Argentina no es obsoleto (también se usa el diminutivo "currito"). Normalmente se utiliza si el trabajo es marginal, ilegal o en la frontera de la ilegalidad. También es posible utilizarlo para trabajos temporales en una forma intercambiable con "changa". Finalmente, puede ser utilizado si el trabajo, a pesar de ser formal/legal, es considerado como plata fácil por el trabajador. En este sentido, el "curro" (o robo) sería cobrar ese dinero por hacer muy poco.

"Empleo" no se utiliza en Argentina como un lugar físico pero sí para otros usos, en particular el desempleo o los índices de empleo según franjas etarias.

Answer (score 2):

One normally uses ¨empleo¨ to define the general aspect of the word ¨work¨, in examples like ¨el nivel de empleo de la region ha aumentado¨ - ¨the level of work in the region has increased¨.
¨Trabajo¨ is used to refer to the activity, as in ¨yo trabajo¨ (¨I work¨), ¨mi trabajo consiste en...¨ (¨my work is to...¨), ¨voy al trabajo¨ (¨I´m going to work - to the office)¨.
¨Curro¨ defines basically the same thing as ¨trabajo¨ but is a more colloquial word, less formal, it is normally used as a regionalism and informally.

Answer (score 2):

"Empleo" is a formal/polite word. It is used in context like tv news, official documents, like "Politica de Empleo".

Trabajo can be used as formal word. In Spain we have the Departament of Trabajo. But is more informal. In a normal conversation with other people you would say "yo trabajo", "he encontrado un trabajo", "he encontrado un puesto de trabajo", etc. It is a Job.

Curro it is more slang. In Spain, most of young people would said "tengo curro". Usually, it is a not well paid job.

Also, if you have a job, and in one particular day, there is nothing to do, you can say "hoy no hay curro", because there is noting to do today.

If you are a person that do a lot of work, you are "currante". Javier es un chico muy currante. It is a positive word, but in a informal chat.

Lower workers are curritos. You use this word if the boss does nothing, and workers are doing the hard job.